# How to plot Standard Deviations

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

Recently I started learning *Probability and Statistics* for Datascience. I am trying to plot **Standard Deviation** for the below distribution `X`, like [68-95-99.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#/media/File:Standard_deviation_diagram.svg) rule.

Code to generate the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Line width: Maximum 130 characters in the output, post which it will continue in next line.
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=130)

sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.5)

# Distribution
X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]

mean = np.mean(X)
var = np.var(X)
std = np.std(X)

print("Mean:", mean)
print("Variance:", var)
print("Standard Deviation:", std)

"""
Mean: 5.0
Variance: 4.0
Standard Deviation: 2.0
"""

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

ax = sns.kdeplot(X, shade=True)

# Plot 1-std
x = np.linspace(mean - std, mean + std)
y = norm.pdf(x, mean, std)
ax.fill_between(x, y, alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel("Random variable X")
plt.ylabel("Probability Density Function")
plt.xticks(ticks=range(0, 10))
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

This code is generating below plot:
[image: Plot]

Questions:

1. What is wrong in the code plotting 1 std from mean?
2. I am not able to understand why there is a small peak above the `kde` plot?
3. How to plot 1-std, 2-std and 3-std?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nothing wrong in your code: mean is `5` and std `2`, so you are shading an area between `5 - 2 = 3` and `5 + 2 = 7`.
2. There is a small peak in the `kde` plot because it is a representation of the data distribution you give with `X` and, actually, `X` is not a normal distribution. You can check this by using a true normal distribution:

   ```
   mean = 5
   std = 2
   X = np.random.randn(10000)
   X = (X - X.mean())/X.std()*std + mean
   ```

   [image]
3. You can plot other standard devaitions with a for loop over `i`. `x1` is the left side, `x2` is the center part (then set to `np.nan`) and finally `x3` is the right side of the distribution. Then you have to set to `np.nan` areas to exclude (which correspond to `x2`):

   ```
   N = 10
   for i in [1, 2, 3]:
       x1 = np.linspace(mean - i*std, mean - (i - 1)*std, N)
       x2 = np.linspace(mean - (i - 1)*std, mean + (i - 1)*std, N)
       x3 = np.linspace(mean + (i - 1)*std, mean + i*std, N)
       x = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3))
       x = np.where((mean - (i - 1)*std < x) & (x < mean + (i - 1)*std), np.nan, x)
       y = norm.pdf(x, mean, std)
       ax.fill_between(x, y, alpha=0.5)
   ```

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Line width: Maximum 130 characters in the output, post which it will continue in next line.
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=130)

sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.5)

# Distribution
X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]


mean = np.mean(X)
var = np.var(X)
std = np.std(X)

print("Mean:", mean)
print("Variance:", var)
print("Standard Deviation:", std)

"""
Mean: 5.0
Variance: 4.0
Standard Deviation: 2.0
"""

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

ax = sns.kdeplot(X, shade=True)

N = 10
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    x1 = np.linspace(mean - i*std, mean - (i - 1)*std, N)
    x2 = np.linspace(mean - (i - 1)*std, mean + (i - 1)*std, N)
    x3 = np.linspace(mean + (i - 1)*std, mean + i*std, N)
    x = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3))
    x = np.where((mean - (i - 1)*std < x) & (x < mean + (i - 1)*std), np.nan, x)
    y = norm.pdf(x, mean, std)
    ax.fill_between(x, y, alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel("Random variable X")
plt.ylabel("Probability Density Function")
plt.xticks(ticks=range(0, 10))
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can u plz point some resource on what you have done in this equation `X = (X - X.mean()) / X.std() * std + mean`?

Comment: `X` is a random distribution generated with [**`numpy.random.randn`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html). It should have mean `0` and std `1`, but actually these values are not mathematically exact because they depend on the numbers picked in the distribution. So mean is _close_ to `1` and std is _close_ to `0`. This approximation improves if you pick a larger distribution, but is will never be mathematically exact.

Comment: So I subtract the actual mean and divide by the actual std, in this way I get a **standard** normal distribution: mean exactly `1` and std exactly `0`. Finally I multiply by `std` and add `mean` (chosen by me) in order to force the random distribution to have mean exactly equal to `mean` variable and std exactly equal to `std` value.